# There is a closest point $x\in C\times C$ ($C$ is the Cantor set) to $y\in C^c$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness, cantor-set

Let $C$ be the Cantor set, $S:=C\times C$. Given: $C\times C$ is compact. Prove that $\exists x \in S$ such that $\lVert k - x \rVert \le \lVert k-y \rVert$, for $x,y \in S$ and $k$ a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash S$.

> Proof:

Fix $k\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash S$ and define the function $f_k:S\to \mathbb{R}$ as $f_k(x)=\lVert k-x\rVert$. Then $f$ is continuous, since norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are continuous. Since $S$ is compact, by the generalized Extreme value theorem, $m:=\inf(f_k) \le f_k \le M:=\sup(f_k)$. This implies that $\lVert k-x\rVert\le M=\lVert k-y \rVert$ for all $y\in S$. Hence, there is a point $x\in S$ which is closest to an arbitrary point $k\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash S$.

Please let me know whether or not my proof is missing some logic.

Comment: That's fine, though the Cantor set was nowhere used. A similar result is important in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, what was used is that $C\times C$ is compact since $C$ is compact.

Comment: That's right, so the compactness of the Cantor set was used. What I meant was, it could have worked with any compact set, right? ($C$ compact, then $C \times C$ compact holds).